# What is the purpose of synovial fluid?

Tags: knee, joints, function

What is the purpose of synovial fluid? From what I understand, this fluid is associated with proper joint-functioning. Not sure if this is accurate. I am curious to learn about its purpose and how it can cause pain.

Comment: Hi, Eileen, and welcome to the site. A little [background research](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/q/353/169) might get you a quicker (or better) answer! Please feel free to take the [site tour](http://health.stackexchange.com/tour) and the [help sections](http://health.stackexchange.com/help) for more information about the site. Thanks, and again, welcome!

Comment: Your query is answerable by searching it on Google. You can find various reliable sources there.